# Bootstrap Page, won't scroll to the end. Container-Fluid already set to min-height: 100%

Tags: html, height

I making a simple bootstrap page, but my last div is cut off. I can't scroll down to it. I've been looking online and I tried adding a min-height to my .container-fluid, but it didn't work. I know this is an easy one, I just can't figure it out.

HTML:

```
<div="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
    min-height: 100%!important;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- add class before equal sign and container-fluid.

2- add height:100% to all parent elements of container-fluid element.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```